# Can I define a query in Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Here's what I have:

```
module EventDependencyProperties
  def start_date
    shows.order('show_date ASC').first.show_date
  end

  def end_date
    shows.order('show_date DESC').first.show_date
  end

  def is_future_show?
    end_date >= Date.today 
  end
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  include EventDependencyProperties
  has_many :shows
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
end
```

I have bits of code elsewhere using the `is_future_show?` method. What I would like to do is have a method in the module mixin to return "future shows" using a query that has the same criteria as the `is_future_show?` method. How would I go about achieving this? I'm very much a newbie to Rails but tainted by knowledge of other languages and frameworks.

Cheers,
Dany.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the query into [a scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes):

```
class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :future, lambda { where("show_date > ?", Date.today) }
end
```

Call it like this:

```
my_event.shows.future
```

**Edit**: Ah I see. To return all events with a show in the future:

```
Event.joins(:shows).where("shows.show_date > ?", Date.today)
```

agains this can be scoped:

```
class Event
  scope :future, lambda { joins(:shows).where("shows.show_date > ?", Date.today) }
end
```

On a side note, I'm not sure about the setup of your models, especially the use of the mixin. Here's what I do:

```
class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event

  # use default_scope so shows are ordered by date by default
  default_scope order("show_date ASC")
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shows
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users

  scope :future, lambda { joins(:shows).where("shows.show_date > ?", Date.today) }

  def start_date
    shows.first.show_date
  end

  def end_date
    shows.last.show_date
  end

  def ends_in_future?
    end_date > Date.today
  end
end
```

also it would be cleaner if the `show_date` column for the Show model was just called `date` (so you could just write `show.date` rather that `show.show_date`).

Comment: Cool - I didn't know that, but that's not quite what I was after. I was thinking about returning an Event that has 1 or more Shows in the future.

Comment: Wow... just when I thought I got a small grasp of ActiveRecord along comes new concepts. That works perfectly thanks! I used show_date in case 'date' clashes with a keyword but obviously it's safe to use.

Comment: Actually - I modified that lambda by adding .group("event_id") so it returns a single Event for those with multiple Shows in the future.